# jQuery Event constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've worked a bit with [jquery tools](http://jquerytools.org/) and I've started browsing through the [twitter bootstrap src](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap).

One thing I've noticed is the use of the `$.Event` constructor for triggering events.

In many cases, (for instance the bootstrap modal) you find events triggered like so:

```
var e = $.Event('show');

this.$element.trigger(e);
```

It eludes me as to why this is better than just directly calling:

```
this.$element.trigger('show');
```

so I'm interested to know what the advantages are to using the jQuery Event constructor.  I've read in the docs that you can attach arbitrary properties to the event, and that makes total sense to me.  What I don't understand however is why it *might* be advantageous to use the constructor if you're not adding any properties to the event at all.

Can someone explain to me why the `$.Event` constructor is an advantage over calling trigger with the event string?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look at the bootstrap source, I believe you must be referring to this:

```
var that = this
    , e = $.Event('show')

this.$element.trigger(e)

if (this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
```

He's defining `e` so that he can later check to see if the default action has been prevented with `e.isDefaultPrevented()`.

Comment: ah... you're absolutely right. I don't know how I missed that.  thx!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more *flexible* if you want to add properties to the event later on; and it helps you to know the *state* of the event after it was triggered, for instance, if someone called [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/) or [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/).

Other than that, jQuery will simply take the event type (`string`), wrap it in a `$.Event` object and normalize it. Here's the relevant source code of jQuery where this happens:

```
event = typeof event === "object" ?
     // jQuery.Event object
     event[ jQuery.expando ] ? event :
     // Object literal
     jQuery.extend( jQuery.Event(type), event ) :
     // Just the event type (string)
     jQuery.Event(type);
```

Comment: While everything here is correct, it doesn't mention the use of `$.Event` in the bootstrap modal plugin. In bootstrap modal he defines the event object so he can check for `isDefaultPrevented` later.

Comment: thanks for the answer João, that gives me more insight into how jQuery works with events, @Fauntleroy got the explanation of this right in the context of bootstrap.  Thanks again!